# [SOLVED]For a point $p$, is the union of two of its neighborhoods the neighborhood with the sum of their radii?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space (in this case $R^2$). Take $p \in X$. For some positive real numbers  $a,b$ ,denote the neighborhoods $N_a(p)$ and $N_b(p)$. Is it true that

$$N_a(p)\bigcup N_b(p) = N_{a+b}(p)$$

My proof:

Denote LHS $A$ and RHS $B$. If $p\in B$ then $p\in N_a(p)$ or $p\in N_b(p)\setminus N_a(p)$. Then $p\in A$. Likewise, if $p\in A$, then $p\in N_a(p)$ or $p\in N_b(p)$. If $p\in N_b(p)$, then $p\in N_b(p)\setminus N_a(p)$. Then $p\in B$. Hence RHS = LHS.

I suspect this is lacking dearly in rigor, but I wasn't sure how to talk about this outside of this basic set theory, if possible.

Comment: Just look at $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric. Is it true that $N_1(0)\cup N_1(0)=N_2(0)$?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to restrict the dimension. Lets say we're talking about $R^2$. Of course your example is false.

Comment: Try the same example in any $\Bbb R^n$, with $0$ being the origin.

Comment: "If $p\in B$ then $p\in N_a(p)$ or $p\in N_b(p)\setminus N_a(p)$" is false. The union of two sets, where one is a subset of the other, is the "larger" of them.

Comment: I see the error in my logic. Thank you. It should just be the larger of the two sets.

Comment: You could mark it as solved.

Comment: There is really no point in adding [SOLVED] in the title. Either add your solution as an answer or delete the question.